# How to convert this into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

My code :-

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $gacookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://merchants.rediff.com/productsajax?callback=jQuery".$twentyone_digit."_".$thirteen_digit."&take=10&skip=10&page=2&pageSize=10&_=".$thirteen_digit."");

$response = curl_exec ($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

It returns :-

```
string(4093) "jQuery859123095956361597167_5643376418178([{"total":53,"ProductID":12959659,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Forward March Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL036","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl036.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12959543,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Womens Right Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL034","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl034.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12959504,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Success Mantra Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL033","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl033.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12959375,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Strength is Life Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL032","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl032.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12959086,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Service to Man is God Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL031","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl031.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12959053,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Respect Women -Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL030","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl030.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12959026,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Grey Vivekananda Women","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL029","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl029.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12958976,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect I wear Strength Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL028","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl028.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12958927,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Have Faith in Yourself First Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL027","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl027.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"},{"total":53,"ProductID":12958850,"IsParent":"1","published":"1","ProductName":"Vivekananda Youth Connect Dream Vivekananda Womens Tshirt","Availibility":true,"ListPrice":"499","WebPrice":"499","vendorSKU":"VYPL025","margin_percent":"20","utime":"07-AUG-2014 15:27:33","ProductImage":"http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl025.jpg","Inventory":"10","jobstatus":"Submitted"}])"
```

When I try to decode, it give me NULL :-

```
$cleanData = json_decode($tempData);
var_dump($cleanData);
```

How can I convert above string into an array ?

**Edit :-**

I tried your code @Glavić and I got the value in array :

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959659 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Forward March Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL036 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl036.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959543 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Womens Right Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL034 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl034.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959504 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Success Mantra Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL033 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl033.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959375 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Strength is Life Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL032 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl032.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959086 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Service to Man is God Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL031 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl031.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959053 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Respect Women -Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL030 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl030.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12959026 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Grey Vivekananda Women [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL029 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl029.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12958976 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect I wear Strength Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL028 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl028.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12958927 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Have Faith in Yourself First Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL027 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl027.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [total] => 53 [ProductID] => 12958850 [IsParent] => 1 [published] => 1 [ProductName] => Vivekananda Youth Connect Dream Vivekananda Womens Tshirt [Availibility] => 1 [ListPrice] => 499 [WebPrice] => 499 [vendorSKU] => VYPL025 [margin_percent] => 20 [utime] => 07-AUG-2014 15:27:33 [ProductImage] => http://imshopping.rediff.com/imgshop/100-100/shopping/pixs/17588/v/vypl025.jpg [Inventory] => 10 [jobstatus] => Submitted ) )
```

Now how can I loop this array stdclass object ?

Comment: `When I try to decode, it give me NULL`. That is because its not a valid json

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `jQuery....( )` part from the string:

```php
$cleanData = substr($string, strpos($string, '(') + 1, -1);
$cleanData = json_decode($cleanData);
print_r($cleanData);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/222801)</kbd>

Comment: thanks I tried your code it worked but see my edit, I have a doubt

Comment: You can loop with `foreach`, like this [demo-object](https://eval.in/222821) or [demo-array](https://eval.in/222828).

Comment: just add second argument `true` to `json_decode` for get pure array

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
$cleanData = substr($string, strpos($string, '(') + 1, -1);
$cleanData = json_decode($cleanData);
print_r($cleanData);


foreach($cleanData as $value) //looping object
{

$value->total; //returns total
...

}
```

Comment: it is exactly, what @Glavić answers

Answer (score 0):

Actually its returning data in jsonp format so there must be place where you can define the function name so jQuery859123095956361597167_5643376418178 replace with function name and it will call automatically call when you call api and json will pass as parameter.

you can refer more about jsonp [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

```
jqueryfunctionname([json]);

function jqueryfunctionname(json){
    //json stuff will be here
}
```